# menus and menuitems now show in odoo 14

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-14

I just recently migrated to odoo 14.

here I am facing an issue with menus.
I have added a menu with menu items but it does not show.

here is my simple code for xml.

```
<menuitem id="root_menu" name="Documents"/>
<menuitem
    id="menu_attachment_document"
    name="Documents"
    parent="root_menu"
    sequence="1"/>
<menuitem
    id="menu_attachment_child"
    name="Documents"
    parent="menu_attachment_document"
    action="base.action_attachment"
    sequence="2"/>
```

Comment: What about your security file? Did you give permission to read

Comment: i've created a model give them access in security file.

Comment: That could be a lot of things: permissions, manifest...